# Save response buffers and send them later in NGINX output body filter

Tags: c++, c, nginx

I know that the output (response) body filter may be called more than once in NGINX, so I wanted to use a cumulative buffer to save the entire reponse body and wrote an empty buffer chain each time by modifying the second input parameter until the last buffer was received (see the following code snippet).

As a result, I found the client could receive the reponse header (chunked response), but it could not receive the reponse body.

```
Server: nginx/1.19.3
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Why or how to do it (save them and send them latter even after `ngx_http_output_body_filter_by_test` is called)?

```cpp
// Use the placement new constructor to all a constructor on an already allocated memory
// buffer = malloc(/*...*/);
// object = new (buffer) MyClass(/*...*/);
// But later you have to call the destructor explicitly too :
// object->~MyClass();
// free(buffer);
// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new
typedef struct ngx_http_test_ctx_s {
    std::string buffer;
} ngx_http_test_ctx_t;

std::string cumulative_buffer;

//@param chain nullable, e.g. rc = ngx_http_output_filter(r, NULL) in nginx\src\http\ngx_http_request.c#ngx_http_writer 
ngx_int_t ngx_http_output_body_filter_by_test(ngx_http_request_t *req, ngx_chain_t *chain) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    logdf("%.*s|%d,%d", ARGS_NGX_STR(req->unparsed_uri), req->headers_out.content_length_n, req->chunked);
    int last = 0;
    for (ngx_chain_t *cl = chain; cl; cl = cl->next) {
        ngx_buf_t *buf = cl->buf;
        // 0/0 if ngx_http_send_special(req, NGX_HTTP_LAST);
        logdf("chain@%p %d%d %" PRIdMAX " / %" PRIdMAX, chain, buf->last_buf, buf->last_in_chain, buf->last - buf->pos, buf->end - buf->start);
        cumulative_buffer.append(buf->pos, buf->last);
        // ngx_chain_update_chains ngx_event_pipe_write_to_downstream
        buf->pos = buf->last; // avoid being write_to_downstream
        buf->flush = 0; // avoid being write_to_downstream
        if (buf->last_buf || buf->last_in_chain) {
            buf->last_in_chain = 0; // avoid being considered as the last buffer by NGINX
            buf->last_buf = 0; //  avoid being considered as the last buffer by NGINX
            last = 1;
        }
    }
    if (last) {
        logdf("cumulative_buffer=%s", cumulative_buffer.c_str());
        // do something use the entire reponse body
        // auto newbuf = reinterpret_cast<ngx_buf_t*>(ngx_alloc_buf(req->pool));
        auto newbuf = ngx_create_temp_buf(req->pool, cumulative_buffer.length());
        newbuf->last = ngx_cpymem(newbuf->last, cumulative_buffer.data(), cumulative_buffer.length());
        newbuf->last_buf = 1;
        newbuf->last_in_chain = 1;
#ifdef ENABLE_NEW_CHAIN_IN_REPONSE_BODY_FILTER
        auto newchain = reinterpret_cast<ngx_chain_t*>(ngx_alloc_chain_link(req->pool));
        newchain->buf = newbuf;
        newchain->next = NULL;
        ngx_int_t rc = ngx_http_next_output_body_filter(req, newchain);
        req->write_event_handler(req); //req->write_event_handler is ngx_http_writer
        return rc;
#else
        // ngx_free_chain(req->pool, chain);
        chain->buf = newbuf;
        chain->next = NULL;

        return ngx_http_next_output_body_filter(req, chain);
        //req->buffered |= NGX_HTTP_SUB_BUFFERED;
#endif
    }
    return ngx_http_next_output_body_filter(req, chain);
    //if (chain) {
    //  req->buffered &= ~NGX_HTTP_SUB_BUFFERED;
    //}

    // Delay the call to the ngx_http_next_output_body_filter function because response may need to be revised.
    // return NGX_OK;
}

static void ngx_http_test_cleanup(void *data) {
    auto ctx = reinterpret_cast<ngx_http_em_subrequest_enforcer_ctx_t*>(data);
    ctx->~ngx_http_test_ctx_t();
    // delete ctx->xx;
    logdf("ctx@%p", ctx);
}
```

After replacing the second `return ngx_http_next_output_body_filter(req, chain);` with `return NGX_OK;`, the client could receive the response body. But, sometime, `last` was always `0` (i.e. no `buf` whose `buf->last_buf || buf->last_in_chain`  is `true`) (content-length vs chunked ?).

```cpp
ngx_int_t ngx_http_output_body_filter_by_test(ngx_http_request_t *req, ngx_chain_t *chain) {
    //// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    logdf("%.*s|content_length_n=%" PRIdMAX ", chunked=%d", ARGS_NGX_STR(req->unparsed_uri), req->headers_out.content_length_n, req->chunked);
    if (req->upstream) {
        logdf("upstream: length = %" PRIdMAX  ", buffer@%p.size=%" PRIdMAX ", bytes_received=%" PRIdMAX ", bytes_sent=%" PRIdMAX
            ", response_length=%" PRIdMAX , req->upstream->length // pending bytes to send to the downstream client
            , req->upstream->buffer.pos, req->upstream->buffer.last - req->upstream->buffer.pos
            , req->upstream->state->bytes_received, req->upstream->state->bytes_sent
            , req->upstream->state->response_length); // req->upstream->pipe->preread_size
    }

    if (NGX_STR_STARTS_WITH(req->unparsed_uri, "/stream/")) {
#if 0
        for (ngx_chain_t *cl = chain; cl; cl = cl->next) {
            ngx_buf_t *buf = cl->buf;
            logdf("chain@%p buf@%p %d%d %" PRIdMAX "/%" PRIdMAX, chain, buf->pos,
                buf->last_buf, buf->last_in_chain, buf->last - buf->pos, buf->end - buf->start);
        }
        return ngx_http_next_output_body_filter(req, chain);
#endif
        if (0 == (intptr_t)ngx_http_get_module_ctx(req, ngx_http_em_module)) {
            ngx_http_set_ctx(req, (void*)1, ngx_http_em_module);
            cumulative_buffer.clear();
        }
        int last = 0;
        for (ngx_chain_t *cl = chain; cl; cl = cl->next) {
            ngx_buf_t *buf = cl->buf;
            // 0/0 if ngx_http_send_special(req, NGX_HTTP_LAST);
            logdf("chain@%p buf@%p %d%d %" PRIdMAX "/%" PRIdMAX, chain, buf->pos,
                buf->last_buf, buf->last_in_chain, buf->last - buf->pos, buf->end - buf->start);
            cumulative_buffer.append(buf->pos, buf->last);
            if (buf->last_buf || buf->last_in_chain) {
                //buf->last_in_chain = 0; // avoid being considered as the last buffer by NGINX
                //buf->last_buf = 0; //  avoid being considered as the last buffer by NGINX
                last = 1;
            }
            //// ngx_chain_update_chains ngx_event_pipe_write_to_downstream
            //buf->pos = buf->last; // avoid being write_to_downstream
            //buf->flush = 0; // avoid being write_to_downstream
        }
        if (last) {
            logdf("cumulative_buffer(length=%" PRIdMAX ")=%.16s", cumulative_buffer.length(), cumulative_buffer.c_str());
            // do something use the entire reponse body
            // auto newbuf = reinterpret_cast<ngx_buf_t*>(ngx_alloc_buf(req->pool));
            auto len = ngx_min(1024, cumulative_buffer.length());
            auto newbuf = ngx_create_temp_buf(req->pool, len);
            newbuf->last = ngx_cpymem(newbuf->last, cumulative_buffer.data(), len);
            newbuf->last_buf = 1;
            newbuf->last_in_chain = 1;
#ifdef ENABLE_NEW_CHAIN_IN_REPONSE_BODY_FILTER
            auto newchain = reinterpret_cast<ngx_chain_t*>(ngx_alloc_chain_link(req->pool));
            newchain->buf = newbuf;
            newchain->next = NULL;
            ngx_int_t rc = ngx_http_next_output_body_filter(req, newchain);
            req->write_event_handler(req); //req->write_event_handler is ngx_http_writer
            return rc;
#else
            // ngx_free_chain(req->pool, chain);
            chain->buf = newbuf;
            chain->next = NULL;

            return ngx_http_next_output_body_filter(req, chain);
            //req->buffered |= NGX_HTTP_SUB_BUFFERED;
#endif
        }
        return NGX_OK; // ngx_http_next_output_body_filter(req, chain);
    }
}
```

## nginx.conf snippet

```
        # /stream/{n} Stream n JSON responses, max n is 100, 59.6 kB, 58690 bytes = 57.314453125 kB
        location /stream/ {
            proxy_buffer_size   4k;
            proxy_buffers   4 8k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 16k;
            # proxy_pass http://httpbin.org;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }
```

I found NGINX didn't retry again after [SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_get_error.html#RETURN-VALUES) ("SSL_write: -1" and "SSL_get_error: 3").

```
>   NGINX.exe!ngx_ssl_write(ngx_connection_s * c, unsigned char * data, unsigned __int64 size) Line 2576    C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_ssl_send_chain(ngx_connection_s * c, ngx_chain_s * in, __int64 limit) Line 2495   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_write_filter(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_chain_s * in) Line 294  C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_chunked_body_filter(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_chain_s * in) Line 219   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_gzip_body_filter(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_chain_s * in) Line 308  C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_postpone_filter(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_chain_s * in) Line 91    C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_ssi_body_filter(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_chain_s * in) Line 413   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_charset_body_filter(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_chain_s * in) Line 557   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_trailers_filter(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_chain_s * in) Line 264   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_output_chain(ngx_output_chain_ctx_s * ctx, ngx_chain_s * in) Line 74  C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_copy_filter(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_chain_s * in) Line 152   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_range_body_filter(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_chain_s * in) Line 635 C
    ngx_http_test_module.dll!ngx_http_output_body_filter_by_test(ngx_http_request_s * req, ngx_chain_s * chain) Line 1148   C++
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_output_filter(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_chain_s * in) Line 1846    C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_send_special(ngx_http_request_s * r, unsigned __int64 flags) Line 3515   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_upstream_finalize_request(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_http_upstream_s * u, __int64 rc) Line 4487 C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_upstream_process_request(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_http_upstream_s * u) Line 4051  C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_upstream_process_upstream(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_http_upstream_s * u) Line 3963 C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_upstream_handler(ngx_event_s * ev) Line 1286 C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_event_process_posted(ngx_cycle_s * cycle, ngx_queue_s * posted) Line 35   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_process_events_and_timers(ngx_cycle_s * cycle) Line 265   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_worker_thread(void * data) Line 795   C
```

I expected (from error.log in the case of a break point),

```
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 reusable connection: 0
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 http upstream temp fd: -1
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 http output filter "/stream/21?"
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 malloc: 0000024099030A50:307242
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 http copy filter: "/stream/21?"
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 http postpone filter "/stream/21?" 000000B5F25FEDE8
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 http chunk: 307242
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 write old buf t:1 f:0 000002409902B468, pos 000002409902B468, size: 156 file: 0, size: 0
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 write new buf t:1 f:0 000002409902CB78, pos 000002409902CB78, size: 7 file: 0, size: 0
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 write new buf t:1 f:0 0000024099030A50, pos 0000024099030A50, size: 307242 file: 0, size: 0
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 00007FF78CC708F8, size: 7 file: 0, size: 0
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 http write filter: l:1 f:0 s:307412
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 http write filter limit 0
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 malloc: 0000024098E6EB50:512
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 malloc: 0000024098E67EC0:16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 156
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 7
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 16221
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 12493
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL buf copy: 7
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL to write: 12500
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 SSL_write: 12500
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 http write filter 0000000000000000
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 http copy filter: 0 "/stream/21?"
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 http finalize request: 0, "/stream/21?" a:1, c:1
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 set http keepalive handler
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 http close request
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 http log handler
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 free: 000002409902EA10
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 free: 0000024099030A50
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 free: 0000000000000000
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 free: 0000000000000000
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 free: 0000000000000000
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 free: 00000240990298B0, unused: 2
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 free: 000002409902A8F0, unused: 12
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 free: 000002409902C970, unused: 3279
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 free: 0000024098E6E710
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 hc free: 0000000000000000
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 hc busy: 0000000000000000 0
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 free: 0000024098E67EC0
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 reusable connection: 1
[debug] 10512#20076: *1 event timer add: 576: 65000:1608876752566
[debug] 10512#20076: worker cycle
```

instead of (really running without any debug breakpoints),

```
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 reusable connection: 0
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 http upstream temp fd: -1
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 http output filter "/stream/22?"
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 malloc: 0000024099030A50:307242
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 http copy filter: "/stream/22?"
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 http postpone filter "/stream/22?" 000000B5F25FEDE8
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 http chunk: 307242
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 write old buf t:1 f:0 0000024098E0C878, pos 0000024098E0C878, size: 156 file: 0, size: 0
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 write new buf t:1 f:0 0000024098E6E188, pos 0000024098E6E188, size: 7 file: 0, size: 0
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 write new buf t:1 f:0 0000024099030A50, pos 0000024099030A50, size: 307242 file: 0, size: 0
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 00007FF78CC708F8, size: 7 file: 0, size: 0
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 http write filter: l:1 f:0 s:307412
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 http write filter limit 0
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 malloc: 0000024098DD79C0:512
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 malloc: 0000024098E67EC0:16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 SSL buf copy: 156
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 SSL buf copy: 7
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 SSL buf copy: 16221
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 SSL buf copy: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 SSL buf copy: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 SSL buf copy: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 SSL_write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 SSL buf copy: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 SSL to write: 16384
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 SSL_write: -1
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 SSL_get_error: 3
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 http write filter 0000024098E6E20C
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 http copy filter: -2 "/stream/22?"
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 http finalize request: -2, "/stream/22?" a:1, c:1
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 event timer add: 576: 60000:1608876912668
[debug] 10512#20076: *3 select add event fd:576 ev:1
[debug] 10512#20076: worker cycle
```

## References

- [Netty User guide for 4.x - Dealing with a Stream-based Transport](https://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html#dealing-with-a-stream-based-transport)
- [ngx_http_sub_filter_module.c](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/modules/ngx_http_sub_filter_module.c) (ngx_http_sub_body_filter). The [`ngx_http_sub_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) module is a filter that modifies a response by replacing one specified string by another.
- [openresty / replace-filter-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/replace-filter-nginx-module/blob/master/src/ngx_http_replace_filter_module.c) `ngx_http_replace_body_filter` - Streaming regular expression replacement in response bodies. [Replace Filter](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules).
- [Writing an Nginx Response Body Filter Module](https://www.nighthour.sg/articles/2017/writing-an-nginx-response-body-filter-module.html) (`ngx_http_html_head_body_filter`)
- [Emiller’s Guide To Nginx Module Development - 4.2. Anatomy of a Body Filter](https://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html#filters-body)

## NGINX References

- [Extending NGINX - Module API - HTTP API - Structures - ngx_http_request_t](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/extending/api/http/?highlight=ngx_http_request_t%23ngx-http-request-t)
- [Extending NGINX - Module API - Memory Management API - ngx_buf_t & ngx_chain_t](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/extending/api/alloc/#ngx-buf-t)
- [NGINX Development guide - HTTP - Request (ngx_http_request_t)](https://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_request)
- [NGINX Development guide - Buffer](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#buffer)
- [NGINX Development guide - HTTP - Header filters (response)](https://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_header_filters)
- [NGINX Development guide - HTTP - Body filters (response)](https://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html%23http_body_filters)
- [Extending NGINX - Module API - HTTP API - Callbacks](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/extending/api/http/?highlight=ngx_http_output_#callbacks)

Comment: What are you building, an nginx module? What is its goal? A little intro would've been nice.

Comment: nginx module. merge chained buffers to a contiguous memory (std::string) and then find the content between two keywords and replace it with a new content.

Answer (score 0):

I haved found the solution to make NGINX send the remaing reponse content to client again (because NGINX only write a part in the next filter and then the socket becomes non-writable) by adding in front of other codes in the filter function.

Now, it looks like

```cpp
ngx_int_t ngx_http_output_body_filter_by_test(ngx_http_request_t *req, ngx_chain_t *chain) {
    if (NULL == chain) {
        return ngx_http_next_output_body_filter(req, chain);
    }
    int last = 0;
    for (ngx_chain_t *cl = chain; cl; cl = cl->next) {
        ngx_buf_t *buf = cl->buf;
        cumulative_buffer.append(buf->pos, buf->last);
        if (buf->last_buf || buf->last_in_chain) {
            last = 1;
        }
        // ngx_chain_update_chains ngx_event_pipe_write_to_downstream
        buf->pos = buf->last; // avoid being write_to_downstream
        buf->flush = 0; // avoid being write_to_downstream
    }
    if (last) {
        // TODO modify chain using cumulative_buffer
        return ngx_http_next_output_body_filter(req, chain);
    }
    return NGX_OK; // ngx_http_next_output_body_filter(req, chain);
}
```

Comment: aren't you going to run out of buffers if the response is large enough?